# SQLite database rowid fail

Tags: android, sqlite, rowid

I've been making an app from some tutorial online in which I'm making a database for storing hotness of girls. For now, it has to be able to store data and view it. Everything is working fine, except that the row-id's that belong to every entry are all NULL when i display them. I tried fixing this for two days solid now, but I haven't got any luck so far. Im kind of a rookie still, can someone with more experience please tell me how to fix this?

The main activity looks like this:

```
public class SQLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button sqlUpdate, sqlView, sqlModify, sqlGetInfo, sqlDelete;
EditText sqlName, sqlHotness, sqlRow;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqliteexample);
    initiate();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bSQLUpdate:

        boolean didItWork = true;
        try{
        String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
        String hotness = sqlHotness.getText().toString();

        HotOrNot entry = new HotOrNot(SQLiteExample.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(name, hotness);
        entry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            didItWork = false;
        }finally{
            if (didItWork){
                print("YESSSS", "it's working!");
            }
            else{
                print("NOOOOO", "Something went wrong");
            }
        }

        break;
    case R.id.bSQLOpenView:
        Intent openView = new Intent(SQLiteExample.this, SQLView.class);
        startActivity(openView);
        return;

    case R.id.bgetInfo:
        String s = sqlRow.getText().toString();
        long l = Long.parseLong(s);
        HotOrNot hon = new HotOrNot(this);
        hon.open();
        String returnedName = hon.getName(l);
        String returnedHotness = hon.getHotness(l);
        hon.close();

        sqlName.setText(returnedName);
        sqlHotness.setText(returnedHotness);

        break;
    }
}

private void initiate() {
    sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLUpdate);
    sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLOpenView);
    sqlModify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLmodify);
    sqlGetInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bgetInfo);
    sqlDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQLdelete);
    sqlName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQLName);
    sqlHotness = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQLHotness);
    sqlRow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQLrowInfo);


    sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlModify.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlGetInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void print(String title, String message){
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle(title);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(message);
    d.setContentView(tv);
    d.show();
};
}
```

The database class:

```
public class HotOrNot {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "persons_hotness";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNotdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"                    
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public HotOrNot(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public HotOrNot open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

The view activity:

```
public class SQLView extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView tv;
Button back;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    initiate();

    HotOrNot info = new HotOrNot(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
}

private void initiate(){
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLInfo);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent back = new Intent(SQLView.this, SQLiteExample.class);
    startActivity(back);
    return;
};
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an SQL syntax error. Change

```
KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
```

to

```
KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
```

i.e. make the underscore a space.

Uninstall your app so that `onCreate()` is invoked again. Since you didn't see an error about the syntax, this version of the SQL was not run.